# Listing tags for a specific commit in Azure Repos using (ADO rest api )

Tags: rest, azure-devops, devops

I would like to see if there is any api that lists all the tags attached to a specific commit

Comment: @Ryguy444222 Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if there is any api that lists all the tags attached to a specific
>   commit

For this issue , you can try the below rest api:

Request url:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/Contribution/dataProviders/query/project/{proId}?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

Sample request body:

```
{
    "context": {"properties": {
        "repositoryId": "46f31875-9df2-4cc7-9f2f-944cf7280d1c",
        "searchCriteria": {
            "gitCommitLookupArguments": null,
            "gitHistoryQueryArguments": null,
            "gitArtifactsQueryArguments": {
                "fetchBuildStatuses": false,
                "fetchPullRequests": false,
                "fetchTags": true,
                "startFromVersion": null,
                "commitIds": ["1a4b0ea9b5c6fe004eb7a0df3e7fa3f146c0db27"]
            },
            "gitGraphQueryArguments": null
        }
    }},
    "contributionIds": ["ms.vss-code-web.git-history-view-commits-data-provider"]
}
```

I catch this api in the `Network` of browser by pressing `F12`. Here is my test in postman:

[image]

Comment: I am confused as why you are using the post call because I would like to make a get call to get list of all the tags of a specific commit in a azure repository

Comment: Because the official document does not provide a rest api to get all tags for a specific commit, so  we can only achieve this by fetching request in the browser's network. The api I can find to meet this demand is using post call. You only need to specify the commitId in the request body to get all tags of this commit.